# WCF: How to get the reference of created instance from ServiceHost (WCF 4.5)

Tags: wcf, instance, servicehost

In my server side console program, multiple ServiceHost objects are created and working in PerSession mode, not singleton.
Therefore, a new server side object will be created when a new session started.

The problem is: How can I know which is the right ServiceHost object linked with the new created server side object? I do need this link information for further operations.

Can I get the ServiceHost information from the new created server side object? By converting it into another interface or class?
Or, can I hook the instance creating process of ServiceHost?

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the `OperationContext` - it has a `.Host` property:

```
var host = OperationContext.Current.Host;
```

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.host.aspx) for more details.